# mysql docker on mac os "crash" on caching_sha2 when laravel connect

Tags: docker, laravel-5, php-7, mysql-8.0

I made factory-reset on my Mac Mini, and I wanna install only Docker and some basic tools like git directly on OS X but other for software I wanna use docker - by other soft I mean app like php, phpstorm, nginx, node, mysql, postgres, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench... in many versions. I wanna install them using docker to easily manage them. For each of this tool I wana to map folder with e.g. code of my projects or db storagem, configuration etc...

During setup mysql 8 I face strange problem - I was able to login as root to db by phpmyadmin and mysql-workbench but my php 7 laravel appliaction "hangs" during connection. Here is mysql dockerfile:

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  db:
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: terefere321
      MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
    - ./db_files:/var/lib/mysql
```

Here is docker file + script which allow me to run php via cmd on docker:

```
FROM php:7.2-apache

COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

RUN apt-get update &&\
    apt-get install -y \
    git \
    zlib1g-dev \
    zip \
    unzip \
    &&\ 
    docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql zip &&\
    a2enmod rewrite
```

Bash script to run php-cmd docker container and "login" to it to get command line:

```
set -e
cd -- "$(dirname "$0")"  # go to script dir - (for macos double clik run)
docker build -t php-cmd .
docker rm -f php-cmd
docker run -d --name php-cmd -v /Volumes/work:/var/www/html php-cmd
docker exec -it php-cmd /bin/bash
```

Here `/Volumes/work` is directory with code of my project. After "login" i run `php artisan migrate` and app hangs for 30s and after throw errors:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away PDO::__construct():
>
> Unexpected server respose while doing caching_sha2 auth : 109

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password` command to mysql8 dockerfile - so you should get:

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  db:
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: terefere321
      MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
    - ./db_files:/var/lib/mysql
```